# How can I detect in a DataGrid if row is clicked and change its column from true to false and vice versa?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, selectionchanged

I'm working on a small WPF application, when I click on a row I'm making my checkbox column selected/unselected. This is how my rows look:

[image]

And here is my code:

```
private void dtgTest_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (dtgTest.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        CheckBox checkbocColumn = (dtgTest.Columns[3].GetCellContent(dtgTest.SelectedItem) as CheckBox);
        checkbocColumn.IsChecked = !checkbocColumn.IsChecked;


        var selectedItem = (BillItemInSerie)dtgTest.SelectedItem;
        var obj = serialNumbersIn.FirstOrDefault(sn => selectedItem.DocumentItemInSeriesId == sn.DocumentItemInSeriesId);
        obj.IsChecked= (bool)checkbocColumn.IsChecked;

    }
}
```

Here is how I'm filling DataGrid:

```
public Test_Window()
   : this()
{
    databaseValues = Controller.Instance.GetById(Id);
    dtgTest.ItemsSource = null;
    dtgTest.ItemsSource = databaseValues;
}
```

So when form is generated I acctually get all items from DB

And here is my XAML:

```
<DataGrid Name="dtgTest"  IsReadOnly="True"  VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"  EnableColumnVirtualization = "True" EnableRowVirtualization ="True"  MaxWidth="4000" MaxHeight="2000" Background="White" Margin="5,5,5,0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowHeaderWidth="0"  HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#0091EA" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#0091EA" CanUserAddRows="False" RowHeight="30" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="2" SelectionChanged="dtgTest_SelectionChanged">
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="DataGridCentering"/>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#0091EA"/>
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{x:Static local:Globals.dataGridfontSizeHeader}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
        </Style>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" 
           Color="LightBlue"/>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn         Binding="{Binding Value1}"          Header=""   Foreground="Black" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Verdana" Width="35*"  />
        <DataGridTextColumn         Binding="{Binding Value2}"          Header=""   Foreground="Black" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Verdana" Width="35*"   />
        <DataGridTextColumn         x:Name="colFormatedDate"            Binding="{Binding ExpireDate, StringFormat ={}{0:MM/yyyy}}"     Header=""   Foreground="Black"      FontSize="15" FontFamily="Verdana" Width="20*" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn     x:Name="colSelektiraj"              Binding="{Binding IsChecked}"       Header=""  Width="10*" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

But issue is here when I click on a row and make checkbox column selected (**LIKE IN EXAMPLE IMAGE ABOVE**) , and If I immediately change my mind and click again on selected row to change the state of checkbox column I won't be able to do it, because `dtgTest_SelectionChanged` won't trigger because I did not change selection..

So I guess detecting if a row is clicked might help me here? So I might execute similar code as it is in `dtgTest_SelectionChanged` event?

Any kind of help would be awesome!
Thanks, guys

Cheers

***EDIT AFTER Rekshino help:***

```
<DataGrid Name="dtgTest" IsReadOnly="True"  VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"  EnableColumnVirtualization = "True" EnableRowVirtualization ="True"  MaxWidth="4000" MaxHeight="2000" Background="White" Margin="5,5,5,0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowHeaderWidth="0"  HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#0091EA" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#0091EA" CanUserAddRows="False" RowHeight="30" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="2" SelectionChanged="dtgTest_SelectionChanged" PreviewMouseDown="dtgTest_PreviewMouseDown">
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="DataGridCentering"/>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#0091EA"/>
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{x:Static local:Globals.dataGridfontSizeHeader}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>
        </Style>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="LightBlue"/>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="dtgTest_PreviewMouseDown"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn         Binding="{Binding Value1}"          Foreground="Black" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Verdana" Width="35*"  />
        <DataGridTextColumn         Binding="{Binding Value2}"          Foreground="Black" FontSize="15" FontFamily="Verdana" Width="35*"   />
        <DataGridTextColumn         x:Name="colFormatedDate"            Binding="{Binding ExpireDate, StringFormat ={}{0:MM/yyyy}}"   Foreground="Black"      FontSize="15" FontFamily="Verdana" Width="20*" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn     x:Name="colSelektiraj"              Binding="{Binding IsChecked, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"     Header=""  Width="10*" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

C# :

```
private void dtgTest_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{

    var cell = sender as DataGridCell;

    if (cell == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    DataGridRow parGridRow = null;
    var visParent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(cell);
    while (parGridRow == null && visParent != null)
    {
        parGridRow = visParent as DataGridRow;
        visParent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(visParent);
    }
    if (parGridRow == null) { return; }

    var selectedItem = (parGridRow.DataContext as BillItemInSerie);
    var obj = serialNumbersIn.FirstOrDefault(sn => selectedItem.DocumentItemInSeriesId == sn.DocumentItemInSeriesId);
    obj.IsChecked = (bool)!obj.IsChecked;
}
```

Comment: Do you want that the click on the row behaves like if checkbox of this row would be clicked?

Comment: @Rekshino Yes something like that, like click once select it, click again on same row without clicking on another and unselect it, and so on, just press clicking on a row and select / unselect it and so on :))

Comment: Do you need to make row unselected or to switch the state of checkbox?

Comment: @Rekshino switch the state of checkbox

Comment: As I posted in my answer - you don't need to handle SelectionChanged for the `DataGrid` element. Further, you override CellStyle from Resources with explicitly set `DataGrid.CellStyle`. Remove it, just to see it works without it.

Comment: I have pasted comments to the XAML in my answer, for you can use additional style for DataGridCell. So again - **remove event handlers for DataGrid** and **remove `<DataGrid.CellStyle>...</DataGrid.CellStyle>`**.

Comment: @Rekshino seems like everything works but I cant figure out why checkbox is not changing value when row is selected, even if it's binded to IsChecked, it's not getting checked.. :/

Comment: There are several reasons - your model doesn't implement INotifiyPropertyChanged, or you don't change IsChecked of object, wich is bound to your check box(you work in event handler with another collection as bound to the ItemsSource). But it is already another issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set mouse event handler for the cell, get the row and make what you want with it. I have removed event handler for `SelectionChanged`, because you don't need it in this solution.

```
<DataGrid Name="dtgTest"  IsReadOnly="True"  VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"  EnableColumnVirtualization = "True" EnableRowVirtualization ="True"  MaxWidth="4000" MaxHeight="2000" Background="White" Margin="5,5,5,0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowHeaderWidth="0"  HorizontalGridLinesBrush="#0091EA" VerticalGridLinesBrush="#0091EA" CanUserAddRows="False" RowHeight="30" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="2">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <!-- If you have to apply another style, then use BasedOn-->
        <!--<Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource DataGridCentering}">-->
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="PreviewMouseDown"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    ...
</DataGrid>

private void PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var cell = sender as DataGridCell; if (cell == null) { return; }
    DataGridRow parGridRow = null;
    var visParent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(cell);
    while (parGridRow == null && visParent != null)
    {
        parGridRow = visParent as DataGridRow;
        visParent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(visParent);
    }
    if (parGridRow == null) { return; }
    var selectedItem = (parGridRow.DataContext as BillItemInSerie);
    var obj = serialNumbersIn.FirstOrDefault(sn => selectedItem.DocumentItemInSeriesId == sn.DocumentItemInSeriesId);
    obj.IsChecked= (bool)!obj.IsChecked;

    //e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: could you follow my XAML and post it as suggestion, that's easier way for me to understand

Comment: this PreviewMouseDown event should be a part of DataGrid event? like dtgTest_PreviewMouseDown ?

Comment: @Roxy'Pro Yes, it is in code behinde of the window.

Comment: this code works, it fires event "PreviewMouseDown" multiple times by clicking on a row, only problem here is cell is null all the time, so it never pass part with { return; }..

Comment: @Roxy'Pro Is `TargetType="DataGridCell` by your side? And `DataGrid` element has no `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown`, but `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` defined only in style?

Comment: You don't need to post all code, but only the code needed to reproduce the issue.

Comment: check for my Edit mate, there in a question I made edit with code posted: XAML & C#

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181138/discussion-between-roxypro-and-rekshino).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a ViewModel (MVVM) which represents the Data for each row. You should/could have a bool property there which represents the CheckBox state (rather than doing so from code behind).

Next, you can Bind DataGrid's SelectedItem to an Object (of relevant type) and test whether that gets fired even when you click same item multiple times. If it does (at least in DevExpress gridControls) - You should Flip the bool property in the Setter for the SelectedItem.

Comment: check for my EDIT, I've posted an xaml

Comment: @Roxy'Pro - You dont have ItemsSource binded to any collection for the Grid. Do you add items to DataGrid from code behind? How is that happening?

Comment: check for my edit, it's happening when form is opened ( in my constructor) I simply get all values from db and set it as items source to my datagrid...

Comment: @Roxy'Pro - Cool - ok thats clears that you are doing stuff from code behind (and not mvvm). Let me write a quick sample and revert.

Answer (score 0):

hi you can set a flag on the binding at the checkboxcolumn.
There is a `NotifyOnTargetUpdated` with fires an `TargetUpdated` event when the target (your checkbox) changes.

With `NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True` on your binding you activate them.
Your `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` looks then like this:

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="colSelektiraj" Binding="{Binding IsChecked, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" Header="" Width="10*" />
```

On the Datagrid use the `TargetUpdated="DataGrid_TargetUpdated"`event to get notified. Your datagrid looks then like this:

```
<DataGrid Name="dtgTest" IsReadOnly="True" TargetUpdated="DataGrid_TargetUpdated" ...>
```

To get notified when the selection changed use the `SelectionChanged` event as you did it already.